# Upgrading IBM Tivoli Monitoring OS agents remotely

Tags: linux, monitoring, tivoli

Does anyone know if there is a way to upgrade IBM Tvoli Monitoring (ITM) OS level monitoring agents remotely? We have a bunch of Windows and Linux servers which need the OS agent upgrade but for Linux we do not have direct ssh access enabled for root user. I do have admin level user account on those servers though. So I can run any command using sudo once I have logged on to the server. Would this be useful for agent upgrade task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further examples (note these are case sensitive) and link to IBM's write up on the command .

```
tacmd updateAgent -t LO -n Primary:*Server Name*:NT -v 062302000
tacmd updateAgent -t NT -n Primary:*Server Name*:NT -v 062303000
tacmd updateAgent -t OQ -n Primary:*Server Name*:NT -v 063002000
```

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v15r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itm.doc%2Fitm_cmdref43.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade OS Agents via the tacmd CLI if the new agent code was loaded in your bundle depot.

1) Log in to you HUB TEMS via tacmd

2) Use the following commands:

```
tacmd updateAgent -t lz -n AGENT:LZ

tacmd updateAgent -t nt -n Primary:Agent:NT
```